# Branch and tag can`t able to delete by API

Tags: git, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

Issue:

After upgrading the GitLab to `10.3.5` from `9.3.6` the branch and tag deleting API is not working if it contains / in the name (example `release/branch`). But it worked older version.

```
C:\Users\test>curl.exe --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:token" "https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/1582/repository/branches/test/test"
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
C:\Users\test>curl.exe --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:token" "https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/1582/repository/branches/testz"
C:\Users\test>curl.exe --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:token" "https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/1582/repository/tags/tag/test"
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
C:\Users\test>curl.exe --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:token" "https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/1582/repository/tags/tagtest"
```

In above curl data, I can able to delete the branch `testz` but `test/test` throw the error Same in `tag` also. How to delete these kinda branches by API?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a URL, there are some characters you can't use outside of context. For example there cannot be a `_space_` in the middle of a URL even though the area represents a String, so you have to use `%20` instead of `_space_`

For `test/test`, you probably need to replace `/` with `%2F`

So test%2Ftest